# In JSF2, could we keep flash parameter more than one redirection on a view?

Tags: jsf-2, prettyfaces, flash-scope

I'm using Mojara 2.2 ,Tomcat 7 and Pretty Faces 3.

I'have a page (called Student) who receives one param from the flash scope.
Then when I refresh the page or execute an h:commandButton adding some stuff in my database, the flash param disappears. I know it's normal ,it's the goal of flash scope, to keep flash param only after one redirect...

But can i make a sort of hacking to keep the value i have passed...still using the flash scope stuff. (I use flash scope because i'm hiding parameter in URL to Student Page and i don't want to change the stuff i have done.)

Thanks

Comment: Once you get that param you can keep it in the `SessionMap` and access it everywhere you want right?

Comment: It's possible. Have a [look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011836/how-to-keep-jsf-flash-scope-parameters-on-page-reload)