# capture refresh event before the server side business logic is hit

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets, browser, jsf-2

This is how I have implemented Flash scope in pages to ensure bean is available after redirection. I am using JSF 2.1.19 shipped with JBoss EAP 6.

**page1.xhtml**

```
<h:commandLink value="#{result.itemVO.number}" action="#{itemBean.goToSecondPage}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{itemBean.itemVO}" value="#{result.itemVO}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

**ItemBean.Java**

This is common bean between both pages.

```
public String goToSecondPage() {
    Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();
    flash.put("itemBean", this);
    flash.setKeepMessages(true);
    flash.keep("itemBean");
    return "secondPage";
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();
    ItemBean itemBean = (ItemBean) flash.get("itemBean");
    //Number
    itemBean.getItemVO.getNumber();
}
```

itemBean object is available from flash in init method after redirection from page1.

But when I do page reload on page 2, flash is empty even if I call setKeepMessages(true). There are lots of fields which I load on the page based on the itemVO but that is not present after reload and the page is rendered blank. Either I want to capture reload event and stop rendering of the page OR I need find a way to persist Flash object in case of reload.

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011836/how-to-keep-jsf-flash-scope-parameters-on-page-reload?lq=1) post to persist the flash object after reload, but it talk about use of EL. But In my case I need to access it in bean post construct method.

I also tried navigation timing api to capture refresh event in javascript as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript). But this is called after bean initialization, which I want to avoid due to some legacy code issues.

Comment: What is your functional problem that you want to prevent with these technical attempts?

Comment: managed bean is getting re-initialized after refresh of the page though the bean is in view scope. This causes improper loading of page.

Comment: [mcve] the and version info since this can have several cause all of which have existung duplicate Q/A in stackoverflow

Comment: @KukeltjeI have edited the question to give more details. And also have gone thru other articles but none seems to resolve my issue.

Comment: Doing a refresh (reload) is a new 'HTTP GET' so effectively a new view *instance* (although the same view), so a new viewscoped bean is used. If you want to have it survive requests, so 'keep alive when accessed in a new view' (new instance of the same view or even a new page) you can  (should) use the DeltaSpike [`@ViewAccessScoped`](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jsf.html#@ViewAccessScoped) and then use normal  `@Inject` into your bean.

Comment: does it mean using only JSF and Javasript, I can not keep alive my bean for page reload?

Comment: Sure you can if you add the required info as url parameters, Flashscope is not meant for this. And using DeltaSpike and OmniFaces is a good choice to begin with. Saves you a lot of 'util' classes and adds additional great features.